# Force Acrobat to use Helvetica instead of Arial, like Ghostscript does

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat

In Word or Excel, on Windows 10, when I print **using a Ghostscript PDF printer**, my PDFs are output with all Arial converted to Helvetica.

**This is good**, since Helvetica looks much better on my screen (the anti-aliasing is *much* better, and [Arial is horrible](https://www.marksimonson.com/notebook/view/the-scourge-of-arial)).

However, when I use **Acrobat Pro DC** to print Arial from Windows 10 applications, the PDFs contain Arial.

Is there a way to 'force' Acrobat to substitute Arial into Helvetica, the way Ghostscript knows to do?

Comment: Microsoft no longer includes Helvitica in its native Font library. I am fairly sure this is a licensing issue and Microsoft did not see a need to license it. I am also fairly sure Adobe followed suit. If you have a license for Helvitica in Word, Adobe may PDF it that way but I do not know much about this angle.

Comment: I can't find any recent announcements that Microsoft planned on stop supporting Helvetica which means it's likely an old decision (1990).  [This](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/how-to-install-helvetica-font-to-acrobat-pro-dc/td-p/9635160?page=1) seems to explain the underline problem.  Try specifically indicate you want to use Helvetica in [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/default-font-pdf-editing-add-text.html#:~:text=Steps%20to%20change%20the%20default,Click%20OK.)

Comment: I think the switch from Helvitica to Arial occurred 15 or more years ago. I had both in Word long ago but that stopped. A user needs to license Helvitica and I am still looking to see if a licensed Helvitica font can be added to Adobe.

Comment: There is information here but (a) it is older and (b) it stumbles on licensing and use   https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/editor-default-font-to-helvetica-not-installed/td-p/9058908?page=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helvetica does not come with any recent version of Acrobat.
The last version of Acrobat that bundled Helvetica was Acrobat 3 back in the mid-1990s.

In the Adobe post from 2015
[How to install Helvetica font to Acrobat Pro DC](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/how-to-install-helvetica-font-to-acrobat-pro-dc/td-p/9635160?page=1),
an Adobe employee named Dov Isaacs answered this:

> The issue is not only that of *installing* a font, but you also need to license the font.
>
> Helvetica is *not* one of the Windows system fonts. Microsoft made a
> decision back in the early 1990s to license and bundle the Arial
> typeface family from Monotype as a metrics-compatible “workalike” font
> to substitute for Helvetica. Within Windows, there are tables to
> equate Arial with Helvetica if no Helvetica is installed.
>
> The problem is that there are many different versions of Helvetica out
> there and most will not be recognized as the simple “Helvetica” from
> the original base-13 PostScript fonts or base-14 PDF fonts. On
> Windows, one source for the “original” Helvetica fonts may be the host
> software CDs or DVDs that accompany true Adobe PostScript printers.

In the post from 2020
[How do I get "Helvetica" fonts for free when I use indesign by the creative cloud?](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/how-do-i-get-quot-helvetica-quot-fonts-for-free-when-i-use-indesign-by-the-creative-cloud/td-p/6887530?page=1),
it was also remarked:

> If you want Helvetica (or Helvetica Neue or Helvetica Now), you must
> purchase a legitimate license of it from Linotype.com (or other font
> resellers licensed to sell it). It's a copyrighted font; there are no
> freebies available.
> https://www.linotype.com/1308886/helvetica-family.html
>
> Please read the above comment about this on February 2015 from Adobe
> engineer Dov Isaacs. it is now 2020 and nothing has changed since his
> post 5 years ago.

Ghostscript might have some licensed variant of the Helvetica font,
and it must be embedding it into the PDF
(since the font won't be found in the OS).
So if you want Helvetica, you need to pass through Ghostscript.

Comment: Thank you, @harrymc, that's very good knowledge.  I had assumed that a purchased copy of Acrobat included Helvetica, since it was one of the original Postscript 35 fonts, and "the mid-1990s" is probably the last time I used it.   At that time, I thought Arial was automagically rendered as Helvetica (maybe before all fonts were embedded all the time, in the dark ages).   I agree, Ghostscript must have some version of 'Helvetica' (possibly a free clone from URW) included within it.